# Keras - cannot import name 'Softmax' from advanced_activations

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, softmax

When I try to import the Softmax layer from advanced_activations

```
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import Softmax
```

I get the error `cannot import name 'Softmax'`

even though Softmax is present in [advanced_activations.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py)

Comment: What's your Keras version? `Softmax` layer is an addition in Keras 2.1.3.

Comment: Try `from keras.layers import Softmax`

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade Keras to 2.1.3 using conda?

Comment: I solved this by using pip to upgrade keras